# HttpContext.Current.Session cannot execute parallel wcf service

Tags: asp.net, web-services, wcf, session, httpsession

I try to call parallel request it's working but if I added this line than not work parallel call.

```
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["UserName"] = "dtest";
```

Any way to call parallel request with the session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was also facing same issue.
Below solution helped me.

```
 if (Context.Request.Path.Contains("xyz.svc"))
 {
       Context.SetSessionStateBehavior(SessionStateBehavior.ReadOnly);
 }
```

Please try and check if this works.